# Loop Count MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop

I am using a for to loop through the values of an array.

```
for i = Sequence

end
```

The i value gives you the value of at that point on the array. But, is there any way to get the position where the array is looping? Example, for is on the first number without setting a new variable count and add +1 every time it loops.

Assume the array has duplicate values.

Comment: Why don't you use `i` as index, and loop over the length of your sequence as `for i=1:length(sequence)` then at every loop you'll have the looping count in `i` and you can access the value in `sequence(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know there is no any inbuilt methods to find loop counter without using additional variable. If you can't use just your `i` variable maybe you can do some workaround about `Sequence` view (using some set of `find` etc.), but I have a strong belief  just to add counter and increase it is a more efficient way.

P.S. By the way try to avoid using `i` and `j` in MATLAB - there are inbuilt variables for imaginary unit:

```
i = 0 + 1i
j = 0 + 1i
```

Comment: As given by this [comment](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/175074-how-to-add-vector-from-cell#comment_264181) this should not really be an issue (regarding using `i`and `j` as variables). Personally I would also recommend to always use `1i` instead of `i` for imaginary values.

Comment: @Nemesis agree with you! Probability of that this `i` and `j` will crash the code is very small, but for me I still prefer use `ii` and `jj` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of doing this it to make your loop index be the counter and then index into your value array

```
for k = 1:numel(Sequence)
    disp(Sequence(k))
end
```